# Can the worst-case analysis of $f(n)$ be $\Omega(g(n))$ but not $O(g(n))$?

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, asymptotics, big-o-notation

I am struggling to wrap my head around using $\Omega$-notation to describe worst-case running time of an algorithm, or $O$-notation to describe the best-case running time. Specifically, I struggle to understand how a given function $f(n)$ can have a worst-case lower-bound of $\Omega(g(n))$ *without also having $O(g(n))$ as the worst-case upper bound*--that is to say, shouldn't all best-case and worst-case complexities be $\Theta(g(n))$?

The core of the issue for me is that once you are describing a case (eg worst-case), you are fixing some characteristic about the nature of the input: *this is the kind of input that makes it take as long as possible*. How can there be multiple analyses of this one type of input?

Answer (score 2):

Let me split the answer to three parts, so it will hopefully clear all misundestandings you have on the concepts.

---

### What are big-O and big-$\Omega$?

Big-O and big-$\Omega$ are two *mqthematical* properties of functions over natural numvers. Their formal definition state that:

- $f=O(g)\iff \exists c>0:\forall n: f(n)\le c\cdot g(n)$
- $f=\Omega(g) \iff \exists c>0:\forall n:f(n)\ge c\cdot g(n)$

See the difference? Big-O talks about bounding a function from **above** and big-$\Omega$ bounds it from **below**.

When we say $f=\Theta(g)$ we actually mean that $f=O(g)$ and $f=\Omega(g)$: $f$ is bounded from above it and below it, by $g$, hence it is "equivalent" to $g$.

---

### Measuring running time

When we measure the *running time* of an algorithm, we usually mean "measure the number of steps it takes to compute the **worst case scenario** when the input is of size $n$". Practically, this means that we want to know what value $T(n)$ is, where $T(n)$ is define as the worst case running time.

Now you can think of $T$ as any other function. Giving a big-O bound to $T$ just means expressing an upper bound on $T(n)$ in nice terms. And giving a big-$\Omega$ bound is just nicely writing a lower bound on $T(n)$.

So essentially, if your running time is both $O(n)$ and $\Omega(n)$, then the time your algorithm takes in the worst case is "equivalent" to a linear function.

---

### Intuitively, what does it say?

Im sure that a big-O bound to the running time of your algorithm is intuitive. However, what does $\Omega(n)$ represent?

Essentially what it says, is that your big-O bound is strict. It means that you have proved your analysis cannot give a better bound on the running time. This property is less useful usually, but becomes more useful the more you are unsure if the big-O bound you gave is strict enough.

For example, try to consider the running time of `heapify` that converts a list of numbers to a heap. Its easy to show an $O(n\log(n))$ bound, and with a little more effort you can even show an $O(n)$ bound. So how can you be sure that you cant get to, say a $O(\log(n))$ bound with even more effort? The answer is simple: we can show an $\Omega(n)$ bound on the running time of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(n) = n^2$. Then we have $f(n) \in \Omega(n)$ but not $f(n) \in O(n)$.

However, as you stated it, it is better to give a tight bound for best and worst cases, with the $\Theta$-notation, because saying "the worst case is exactly $n^2$ operations" is a better information than "the worst case is at least $n$ operations".

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my other answer for a long explanation on the topic.

---

However, the short answer would be: yes, every function $f$ is $\Theta(f)$, but we want to know what that value actually is. Is that $\Theta(n)$? Or maybe its $\Theta(n^2)$? The idea is that we want some simple function that will represent the (more complex) function of the running time.

Comment: Why not remove this answer, and put the short answer at the beginning of your other post?

Comment: I think it will just make the other post unnecessarily longer. The aim of my other answer is to explain what big-O and big-$\Omega$ are, and how they are related to "computing the runtime of an algorithm", but it does not directly address the question the OP asked. This answer, however - doesn't explain the intuition \ usefulness in big-O and big-$\Omega$, but instead directly answers (hopefully) the OP's question.